# mod_geoip2 + geoip web service

Tags: apache, geoip

I have searched around for hours on the MaxMind site and various forums not finding the answer.  Hopefully this has not already been asked.

I am interested in using mod_geoip2 with the geoip web service.

It looks like out-of-box mod_geoip2 works with local database file(s) to do lookups.  But what if I am a premium user that wants to do lookups using their web service?  Can this be done with mod_geoip2, or is it ONLY going to work with a downloaded local database file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mod_geoip2 only works with the downloadable database files.